# 02 chevy cavalier skidding when braking

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, cavalier

So I've done a lot of under body work on my 02 Chevy cavalier z24, the most recent being the sway bar, rack and pinion and last week the struts. Around the time we did either the sway bar or the rack I had to come to a quick stop and the car skidded. I wrote it off to the rain but just to be sure I re-enacted the same while it was dry out and same results.

We looked online and all signs pointed to my struts but with them now new still same results. My drive shaft does need replacement but I would like opinions on what the issue could be besides the drive shaft.

Also since the rack was replaced there has been a popping noise like the parts shift when I turn or brake.

Could it be possible we missed something or maybe need a part the last owner could have missed?

I've looked extensively online and the answers keep me guessing...

Comment: An '02 Cav should have ABS all the way around. Was it only one wheel, two, or all four wheels which lock up and cause the skid? Anyway you look at it, I would consider that you have an ABS issue. Does the light for the ABS come on when you turn the car on? (Meaning, does it blink on, then go out ... or maybe it doesn't come on at all?) When the ABS self diagnostics happen, it should blink on then off. If you don't see it at all, it means the bulb is burnt out, or  the bulb was taken out. I point this out incase there is a hidden ABS issue which is being masked by the lack of a dash light.

Comment: Is the vehicle lowered or at stock height? If stock height, a bad CV joint could contribute to wheel locking, the issue is probably in a brake, the braking system and/or ABS. A lowered vehicle could have binding problems.

Answer (score 3):

*It's possible* that the brake booster line was disconnected during your work.  Check the brake booster valve and hose and ensure they are connected/functioning.

The valve for the brake booster is where the line attaches too in the brake booster.

***Image of brake booster line, valve and booster***

[image]